# Apache Hadoop 2.7.3, Socket Timeout Error

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I have same issue as in the below link.

[Hadoop, Socket Timeout Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940834/hadoop-socket-timeout-error/46372493?noredirect=1#comment79704484_46372493)

Can you please help me with the solution,I have same issue on Apache Hadoop 2.7.3 EC2 installation.Does the properties mentioned in the link needs to be added to both name and data node config files ? If yes, what all .xmls ? Thanks in advance.

Also application is trying to access internal ip on EC2 as per below error,do I need to open up any ports ? It says 8042 on Web UI.

All the nodes and Nodemanager and Resource Manager(RM) are shown running at jps.

Error from Namenode when I tried to run the map reduce example is below:

Job job_1506038808044_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1506038808044_0002 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1506038808044_0002_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From ip-172-31-1-10/172.31.1.10 to ip-172-31-5-59.ec2.internal:43555 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ip-172-31-5-59.ec2.internal/172.31.5.59:43555]

Finally the RM web UI has below message all the time the job was running:

Status : waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.

Thanks,
Asha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the solution present at Hadoop, Socket Timeout Error(link in my question) and adding below to hdfs-site.xml file,the issue was resolved by allowing all ICMP and UDP rules to the ec2 instances so they can ping between each other.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.block.size</name>
  <value>134217728</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout</name>
  <value>2000000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.socket.timeout</name>
  <value>2000000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether datanodes should use datanode hostnames when
    connecting to other datanodes for data transfer.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>
    The actual address the RPC server will bind to. If this optional address is
    set, it overrides only the hostname portion of dfs.namenode.rpc-address.
    It can also be specified per name node or name service for HA/Federation.
    This is useful for making the name node listen on all interfaces by
    setting it to 0.0.0.0.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-bind-host</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>
    The actual address the service RPC server will bind to. If this optional address is
    set, it overrides only the hostname portion of dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address.
    It can also be specified per name node or name service for HA/Federation.
    This is useful for making the name node listen on all interfaces by
    setting it to 0.0.0.0.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-bind-host</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>
    The actual address the HTTP server will bind to. If this optional address
    is set, it overrides only the hostname portion of dfs.namenode.http-address.
    It can also be specified per name node or name service for HA/Federation.
    This is useful for making the name node HTTP server listen on all
    interfaces by setting it to 0.0.0.0.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.https-bind-host</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>
    The actual address the HTTPS server will bind to. If this optional address
    is set, it overrides only the hostname portion of dfs.namenode.https-address.
    It can also be specified per name node or name service for HA/Federation.
    This is useful for making the name node HTTPS server listen on all
    interfaces by setting it to 0.0.0.0.
  </description>
</property>
```